# Only need the first task, ignore the rest

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to call a task at a specified interval. And avoid calling a new task unless the last has already completed.

```
private async void OnTimerTick(object sender, object e)
{            
    if (_criticalSection.IsEntered()) return; // only allow 1 at any given time, ignore the rest
    using (var section = await _criticalSection.EnterAsync())
    {
        await update();
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this? Any suggestions for a better pattern?

Comment: Your code is not threadsafe, it is a race.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: you mean there's a race between the release in the continuation  of the using block and IsEntered? but if the SynchronizationContext is the same, how can there be a race?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A critical section (like a Window's mutex) is for *mutual exclusion*: only allowing a single thread into a code path.

But that's not what you are trying to do: you need something that will tell you if something is happening.

A better approach would be a Manual Reset *Event*: set it (also know as *signalled*) at the start of the task and reset at the end. Then you can check if it is signalled by waiting on it with a timeout of zero for a normal Window's event, or with the applicable member for other types of event.

As this appears to be all in a single process a good starting point is [`System.Threading.ManualRestEventSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Used something like:

```
// One off initialisation somewhere at class scope
private static ManualResetEventSlim taskRunning = new ManualResetEventSlim();
private static object taskLock = new Object();

// code called from the timer, do in a lock to avoid race conditions with two
// or more threads call this.
lock (taskLock) {
  if (!taskRunning.IsSet) {
    StartTheTask(); // assuming this does not return until task is running.
  }
}

// At the outermost scope of the code in the task:
try {
  Debug.Assert(!taskRunning.IsSet); // Paranoia is good when doing threading
  taskRunning.Set();

  // Task impementation

} finally {
  Debug.Assert(taskRunning.IsSet); // Paranoia is good when doing threading
  taskRunning.Reset();
}
```

Another approach would be to always start the task, but have it check the event, if set then immediately exit. This would still need the `lock` to avoid races between the `IsSet` and `Set()` calls across threads. This second approach keeps the checking code together at the cost of briefly having another task running (unless that is common I would likely take this approach for the code locality).

Comment: Nice and quick response, thanks. But what is the reasoning behind Win32's TryEnterCriticalSection(), and SemaphoreSlim's timeout parameter? Aren't they logically applicable?

Comment: @user3127135 As noted in the answer critical sections (like muxtexes) are the wrong kind of synchronisation objects. A semaphore could be used, but you don't need the count it provides: it would be more complicated.

Comment: And is there any difference between using ManualResetEventSlim and a thread-safe boolean flag?

Comment: @Ricard. Ah, I see. It can provide the means, but it's not what it should be used for. Both for readability, complexity and intention. OK, good :)